# Referencing web root directory in launchSettings.json?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set an environment variable in my "launchSettings.json" that has the full path to a DLL file that is in the root of my IIS site web folder.

It works if I put the physical path in C:\Projects\VisualStudio.." but is there a way to dynamically reference the site root project folder?

I have tried just the DLL without a path, something like %IIS_SITES_HOME% but doesn't seem to work.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55270/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "PROFILER_PATH": "Sample.dll"
        // "PROFILER_PATH": "%IIS_SITES_HOME%/Sample.dll"
      }
    },
    "AspNetCoreMvcSample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55271/"
    }
  }
}
```

My environment variable is called "PROFILER_PATH"

Comment: You should use other environmental variables than `IIS_*`, as they are only valid inside IIS Express processes, but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

If the DLL is part of your project, you need to reference it appropriately in your project and put it in the **bin** folder and it will be automatically picked up without writing any code or settings.

But if the DLL is just a file that your project will do something with, then it is probably better to place it in some subfolder. Anyway, you don't need any setting for the folder, you can simply access it using:

```
Server.MapPath("~");
//Server.MapPath("~/Sample.dll");
```

If you're using in in a class other than a controller, you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
//HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Sample.dll");
```

Comment: The problem is I want to reference in the JSON payload. I don't have access to the code and the Server.MapPath is not set :(

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid you have to use the value of `applicationUrl` which is `http://localhost:55270/`, so your variable will be `"PROFILER_PATH": "http://localhost:55270/Sample.dll"`.